# How to get proper coordinates of a ellipse according to the image drawn in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to use Fabricjs to draw ellipse over a image where user can also zoom in/out and draw which is further saved to server to be seen in Android apps.

But I am unable to get proper coordinates to be saved to server.

Suppose user zoom in to some extent ,say scaleX @1.5 and draws a ellipse over the image and then tries to save .

How can I get the respective left and top of ellipse according to the image @ scaleX of 1.0 ,because Android follows their Aspect Ratio and always respects 1.0 as a good scale value and the coordinates associated with scale of 1.0 are easily drawn on Android, whereas scaleX@1.5 is totally disturbing the ellipse location.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/h2zvj3un/27/), you can zoom in/out to see the logs(coordinates) as HTML content under the canvas. 
You could use your mouse to free draw a ellipse (Zoom to see the logs changing).

Code :

 `//Please check Fiddle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/h2zvj3un/28/

Do not try to write your own zooming function, the library you are using already have one and allows you to work with normal coordinates without using any scaling factor.

```
   function _zoom(e, dragDelta) {  
     var evt=window.event || e;
     var delta = (dragDelta == undefined) ? evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta : dragDelta;
     var curZoom = canvas.getZoom(),  newZoom = curZoom - delta / 400,
         x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;

     var objects = canvas.getObjects();
     //applying zoom values.
     canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: x, y: y }, newZoom);
     var ellipse = objects[1];
     var image = objects[0];
     var ix = image.left;
     var iy = image.top;
     var ex = ellipse.left;
     var ey = ellipse.top;

     document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML = "Circle Left : " + ex + "<br/>" + "Circle Top : " + ey + "<br/>Image Left : " + ix + "<br/>" + "Image Top : " + iy + "<br/> Image ScaleX : " + image.scaleX + "<br/>Circle ScaleX" + ellipse.scaleX + "<br/> Expected data coordinates to be sent to server is (last left - new left/new scale, last top - last top/new scale) -> (" + (ex - ix) + ", " +  (ey - iy) + ")";

     canvas.renderAll();
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
 }
```

Using canvas.zoomToPoint you can zoom at will and not be worried about changing coordinates of objects and scale factor.

Comment: Yes Thanks for the answer . That is what I was looking for from last 1 month. But there is a small issue with the zoom. If you zoom in/out to some more extent, it flips vertically ..any idea why?

Comment: because scale goes under 0. insert a check so that newZoom does not go under 0.

Comment: yes that's true . Thank you for the help . [Updated answer](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/h2zvj3un/32/)

Comment: I can see the zoom functionality works in reverse manner where zoom in happens on mouse down and vice versa . Also the zoom works properly in Chrome but not very properly on Firefox . Any idea, why?

Comment: Well , changing from "-" to  "+" solved the zoom reverse issue `    newZoom = curZoom + delta / 2000` , but still no idea why firefox behaves strangely

Comment: Also, I wrote some code on my own to move the image on mouse drag. That's not working properly as well. Is it because of ZoomToPoint() ?

Comment: fabricjs has also drag functionality ( of zoomed canvas ) you should use those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: I face the same issue for positions in case of image dragging . `        var panning = false;
   canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
       panning = false;
   });

   canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
       panning = true;
   });
   canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
    if (panning && e && e.e) {
     var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
     canvas.relativePan(delta);
     relativePanDeltaX = e.e.movementX;
     relativePanDeltaY = e.e.movementY;
     
    }
   });    `

Comment: Added answer below where I am failing